# Redux - call action from a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to call a redux action from a function. The component that I'm calling the function from is already connected to the store. However, it doesn't work if I pass the action such as:

```
function myFunc(action) {
    action()
}
```

Is there a way to pass an action via a parameter? Thank you.

Comment: You need to dispatch your function to the redux store. Since it is not a complete code, it's hard to give suggestions based on that. If you use it in `React.Component`, using "react-redux" connect function with a mapActionToProps, you can access the action in the react props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action must be connected to a dispatch for the reducer to catch it and update the store.

In order to do this you should include your action as a `mapDispatchToProps` arg for redux's connect function. It would look like this:

`connect(null, { actionCreator })(MyComponent)`

To pass the connected action creator to a function from within the component, access it via props: `myFunc(this.props.actionCreator)`

Putting it all together:

```
import myFunc ...
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  onChange() {
    myFunc(this.props.actionCreator)
  }

  render() { ... }
}

export connect(null, { actionCreator })(MyComponent)
```

Now when `myFunc` executes `actionCreator()` it will properly dispatch the action to be caught by your reducer.

Answer (score 4):

using `bindActionCreator` from redux is the easiest way to dispatch actions from the component.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class ReduxConnectedComponent extends React.Component {
 mainFunction = () =>{
  this.props.someAction(); // this dispatches your action.
  }
 render(){}
}
const mapStateToProps = store => ({
  test: store.modules.someObject,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
  someAction: yourActionCreatorFunction,
}, dispatch);
export default connect(maStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ReduxConnectedComponent)
```

here in mapDispatchToProps, we are using `bindActionCreator` to bind a function to `redux` `store` `dispatch`. so that whenever you call it. it actually dispatches the store action

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED APPROACH 2021**

You can use hook now to dispatch any action
At first import `useDispatch` from `react-redux` like bellow

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
```

Now inside your functional component create a variable like bellow

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

now dispatch/call any action like bellow from anywhere

```
dispatch(action());
```