# React ES6: calling async function from another function not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is where I call `register()`:

```
this.register();
```

Here's the `register()`:

```
register = async () => {
    await login();
    await create();
}
```

Here are the ones I call:

```
login = () => {
    console.log('test');
}
```

Ideally, what I want is to finish `login()` first, then go to `create()`.

Error I get:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: login is not defined

Comment: `await this.login()`?

Comment: The error means that at the moment you are trying to call `login`, it doesn't exist yet. You need to provide a [mcve] for us to be able to tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you will probably need to complete the question with more context. In general, in Javascript, if you are working with classes, you will need to bind the context:

```
this.login = this.login.bind(this)
```

and then call `this.login()`

Moreover, in the case of `react/redux`, if your `login` function is not in your component you will probably have to `connect` your component and tell Redux what is the function you'll use, as explained here: [Redux - call action from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52906589/redux-call-action-from-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I was calling a normal function inside an Async function. Even though the async function was called directly on the button click, it still needed binding (*this.function= this.function.bind(this)*). The function I was calling did not need Binding itself, which wasn't consistent with what I've encountered before with binding.